# How can I reshape my numpy array from (512) to (512,) in Python 3.x?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, numpy, multidimensional-array, reshape

I am a new one in python. For maniputing the numpy array, I tried to reshape an array size several times like my expectation. But didn't cover it up.
Currently my array shape is 512
But I want to change it into the shape of (512,)
How can I do this?

aa= my_obj.highpasses.reshape(512,)
Error comming

Comment: `(512)` is not a possible shape. Show us the exact, complete error message, including full stack trace.

Comment: `(512,)` is just syntax for a tuple containing only the integer 512. There's no difference between the two shapes you're describing, so the idea of resizing between them doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Try this once: `aa = my_obj.highpasses.reshape((512,))` instead of `aa= my_obj.highpasses.reshape(512,)` because the `reshape` function takes a tuple as an argument representing the desired shape of the array. In this case, you provide (512,), indicating that you want a 1-dimensional array of size 512.